# How does glClear() improve performance?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

[Apple's Technical Q&A on addressing flickering (QA1650)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1650.html) includes the following paragraph. (Emphasis mine.)

*You must provide a color to every pixel on the screen. At the beginning of your drawing code, it is a good idea to use glClear() to initialize the color buffer. A full-screen clear of each of your color, depth, and stencil buffers (if you're using them) at the start of a frame can also generally **improve** your application's performance.*

On other platforms, I've always found it to be an optimization to *not* clear the color buffer if you're going to draw to every pixel. (Why waste time filling the color buffer if you're just going to overwrite that clear color?)

How can a call to glClear() improve performance?

Comment: It has not been the case that neglecting to clear the color/depth/stencil buffer would be a performance optimization for many years. As explained in some of my comments on the other answers, it has to do with buffer compression in modern GPUs. By modern GPUs I am talking as far back as the Radeon 9xxx series. Clearing these buffers is actually a performance gain on virtually all GPU architectures.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is most likely related to tile-based rendering, which divides the whole viewport to tiles (smaller windows, can be typically of size 32x32) and these tiles are kept in faster memories. The copy operations between this smaller memory and the real framebuffer can take some time (memory operations are a lot slower than arithmetic operations). By issuing a glClear command, you are telling the hardware that you do not need previous buffer content, thus it does not need to copy the color/depth/whatever from the framebuffer to the smaller tile memory.

Comment: If you need more details, check out these references:
- http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/gdc2008_ribble_maurice_TileBasedGpus.pdf 
- http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/38/

Comment: It is related to color/depth/stencil compression as well. In a nutshell, clearing the buffer through proper means will make each tile (*this applies to regular GPUs too, not just Tile-Based Deferred Rendering ones like those from PowerVR*) easier to compress and improve throughput. Compression of these buffers is not done to save storage space, but to reduce the amount of data that has to be transferred. Clearing the tiles is a trivial matter of setting a few bits in each tile and once done, a cleared tile is very cheap to fetch from memory.

Answer (score 3):

With the long perspective of official comments on iOS 4, which postdates the accepted answer...

I think that should be read in conjunction with Apple's comments about the `GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer` extension, which should always be used at the end of a frame if possible (and indeed elsewhere). When you discard a frame buffer you put its contents into an undefined state. The benefit of that is that when you next bind some other frame buffer, there's never any need to store the current contents of your buffer out to somewhere, and similarly when you next restore your buffer there's no need to retrieve them. Those should all be GPU memory copies and so quite cheap, but they're far from free and the iPhone's shared memory architecture presumably means that even more complicated considerations can crop up.

Based on the compositing model of iOS it's reasonable to assume that that even if your app doesn't bind and unbind frame buffers in its context, the GPU has to do those tasks implicitly at least once for each of your frames.

I would dare guess that the driver is smart enough that if the first thing you do is a clear, you get half the benefit of the discard extension without actually using it.

Answer (score -3):

Try decreasing the size of your framebuffer in the glSurface attributes that you pass to ChooseConfig.

For example, set attributes to 0 for minimum or omit them completely to use defaults unless you have a specific requirement.

Answer (score -5):

I can definitely confirm that you have to *provide a color to every pixel on the screen*.

I've verified this in a bare bones test app built on XCode's iPhone OpenGL template:

```
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];  
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

If I leave out the `glClear` line (or move it further down in the loop, after some other OpenGL calls), the thread (running via `CADisplayLink`) is hardly getting any updates anymore. It seems as if CPU/GPU synchronization goes haywire and the thread gets blocked.
Pretty scary stuff if you ask me, and totally not in line with my expectations.

BTW, you don't neccessarily have to use glClear(), just drawing a fullscreen quad seems to have the same effect (obviously, a *textured* quad is more expensive). It seems you just have to invalidate all the tiles.

Comment: **-1**: You should use `glClear (...)`, modern GPUs use color buffer, depth buffer and stencil buffer compression. Clearing the buffer is extremely cheap because these buffers are often hierarchically tiled, and the process of clearing the buffer amounts to flipping one or two bits in each tile. It even helps with many early fragment tests and general frame buffer throughput if you regularly clear the buffers. On Tile-Based Deferred Rendering GPUs (e.g. PowerVR SGX - all iOS devices) it is equally important for similar reasons.