# Clearing the color buffer in OpenGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing an iPhone app that uses OpenGL ES to draw the graphics onscreen. With each new frame i draw to the entire screen, which brings me to my question. Is it necessary to call glClear to clear the color buffer each frame or can i just overwrite it with the new data? The glClear function is currently 9.9% of the frametime so if i could get rid of it it would provide a nice boost.

Forgive me if this is a very naive question as i am something of a noob on the topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily trust that 9.9% frame time measurement. Due to the deferred nature of the iOS GPUs, it's really difficult to profile specific calls like this in a rational way. Odds are, `glClear()` is not really taking that much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a static scene that doesn't need re-drawing, then you could skip the call to `glClear()` for the color buffer.

From the [Khronos OpenGL ES docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClear.xml):

> **glClear** sets the bitplane area of the window to values previously selected by **glClearColor**.
>
> **glClear** takes a single argument indicating which buffer is to be cleared.
>
> **GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT** Indicates the buffers currently enabled for color writing.

Comment: Actually, one could skip the calls to all drawing functions as well in that case.

Comment: Of course. But since this question specifically asks about the color buffer, I didn't want to overwhelm with too much additional info :)

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you can leave it out.

But if you don't clear the color buffer, the previously drawn data will stay on screen.
That limits applications to such with non-modifying data.

Answer (score 0):

Typically (when making 3D games) you don't clear just the color buffer, but the depth buffer as well and use depth test to make sure that the stuff that's closest to the camera is drawn. Therefore it is important to clear the depth buffer, otherwise only pixels with lower Z value than in the previous frame would be redrawn. Not clearing the color buffer would also be problematic when drawing transparent things.

If you're making a 2D application and manage the drawing order yourself (first draw the stuff that's furthest away from camera, and then what is closer a.k.a. painters algorithm) then you can leave out the clear call. One thing to note is that with such algorithm you have another problem - *overdrawing* i.e. drawing the same pixels more often than necessary.

Comment: Also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538662/how-does-glclear-improve-performance)